# "best_split_info" check failure encountered while fitting LightGBM classifier

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost, lightgbm

I came across the following error while fitting a LightGBM classification model. All of the features in use are numerical with around 20% missing values. The target variable is binary. Could I know how this error (**Check failed: best_split_info.left_count > 0**) is resulted?

```
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier


lgb_model = LGBMClassifier()
lgb_model.fit(train[predictors], train['is_booked'])
```

[image]